# magento 2 - In what case we need to run this command magento setup:di:compile?

Tags: magento2, extensions, cli

In what case we need to run this command `magento setup:di:compile` ?

Comment: Once you have installed new modules and want to clear some directries

Comment: and anything else?

Comment: Also when you switch to production mode because in that mode, no static content is generated; it's all served from `pub/static`

Answer (score 8):

- During deployment (i.e. when changes were made to a system in production mode)

  Note that in production mode (versions 2.0.5 and earlier) you must use the "multi-tenant" compilation. Fixed in 2.0.6 and later.

  ```
  bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant
  ```

  See: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html
- You can also use compilation in development mode, which should speed up the site, but on the other hand it slows down development, because you will need to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` everytime you **added new classes with dependencies** (constructor parameters) or **changed dependencies of existing classes**.

  This is optional, and it's probably not a good idea. If you already ran the compilation in your development environment, delete the files in `var/di` to disable it.

Comment: setup:di:compile-multi-tenant has been removed

Comment: Can we please get some confirmation as to whether deleting the var/di folder trick works? It doesn't seem to for me

Comment: @Wildcard27 what if you also delete the directories in `var/generation`?

Comment: @FabianSchmengler Have just created an `Action` to test. -- Loaded the page, error. -- Deleted `di` and `generation` folders, reloaded, works. -- Add new dependency, reload page, error. However no `di` folder is generated. 
 -- Delete `generation` again, reload, works. Conclusion: Delete the generation folder after adding dependencies and you won't have to run `setup:di:compile`. If someone else could confirm this, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment on another answer:

You can avoid running the `setup:di:compile` command after every time you add a depency by just deleting the `var/di` and `var/generation` folders **before reloading the page**.

From my own tests, Magento will recreate the `var/generation` folder, but not the `var/di` folder until `setup:di:compile` is ran again. This means you should only have the `var/generation` folder to delete.

Funnily enough, this also works with `pub/static/*` and `setup:static-content:deploy`. This is because Magento seems to create symlinks to the files needed if the static content is built by page reload, rather than CLI.

People in our office were having problems running the above commands whilst using Docker for Mac. The file processing was just too slow. By using the steps above, development should be much quicker.

It's probably best to note that this will not work when in production or default mode. This is only for development. As mentioned by Fabian Schmengler, initial page reload will be slower than normal, but shouldn't be as slow as running `setup:static-content:deploy` or `setup:di:compile.

For reference, I am running version **2.1.5**.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Alan Storm's blog](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_di_compile_pre-scan_with_commerce_bug/).

**Dependency Injection Compilation**

To start, we should explain the problem these commands are trying to solve. When you ship a Magento 2 system to production, you need to run the following command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

This commands scans through the code in your system and pre-generates a number of things (mostly related to the object manager system and dependency injection) that Magento dynamically loads when you’re running in developer mode. This is both a performance and security thing, and discussing it in full is beyond the scope of this article.

Comment: "This is both a performance and security thing, and discussing it in full is beyond the scope of this article." this gave it away. blatant copy from Alan Storm: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_di_compile_pre-scan_with_commerce_bug/